# How to check if asp.net mvc 3 is installed?

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to write a powershell script that would install asp.net mvc 3 if it is not already installed. How do i check if a specific version of asp.net mvc 3 is installed?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I think you can't change the location of the install folder, so you could probably just:

```
test-path "${Env:ProgramFiles(x86)}\Microsoft ASP.NET\ASP.NET MVC 3"
```

Answer (score 3):

Another way (unfortunately quite a bit slower) is to query WMI:

```
$res = Get-WmiObject Win32_Product | Where {$_.Name -match 'ASP\.NET MVC 3'}
if ($res -ne $null) { ... }
```

Comment: I strongly recommend avoiding the use of Win32_Product. First, it is really, really slow (that query could take minutes). Second, *you can screw up your system* because the Win32_Product class works by enumerating every MSI package that is installed, which results in a reconfiguration and validation (and repair if the application is found to be inconsistent with the original MSI) http://support.microsoft.com/kb/974524

Comment: Yeah I noticed it was indeed incredibly slow.  Good to know about the potential issues. Still, it seems like there should be a WMI way to determine this.  Relying on reg keys or paths seems a bit brittle.

Answer (score 2):

I got curious, and made a Win32_AddRemovePrograms class http://poshcode.org/2470 ... that works, but honestly, you don't need that to check on a specific product, you can just look for that product's ID in the registry.

```
test-path "hklm:\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\{DCDEC776-BADD-48B9-8F9A-DFF513C3D7FA}"
```

Where {DCDEC776-BADD-48B9-8F9A-DFF513C3D7FA} is the product ID for Asp.net MVC 3.  You could double check to make sure by checking the display name for it:

```
(Get-ItemProperty "hklm:\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\{DCDEC776-BADD-48B9-8F9A-DFF513C3D7FA}" DisplayName).DisplayName -eq "Microsoft ASP.NET MVC 3"
```

Comment: And {D32EF103-4016-4C15-BCB0-700C0A7A2309} for the MVC 3 security update.