# How to check MVC 3.0 installed on my computer using javascript or C# code?

Tags: c#, javascript

How to check, MVC 3.0 is installed or not on my computer, using javascript or C# code?

Comment: This will get you on the way: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8856118/how-can-i-check-the-asp-net-mvc-version-running-on-a-server-with-a-aspx-file

Comment: This answer uses PowerShell, but you could do a Directory.Exists() in C# http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4750305/how-to-check-if-asp-net-mvc-3-is-installed

Comment: Abbas/Jason, Can you pls share me any code snippet in C# or Javascrpit regarding this.